# How to remove duplicate values of a data set and take the count of how many times each value duplicated?

Tags: r

I am getting a data set each month with unique reference IDs which contains duplicate values. I have to remove the duplicate unique IDs and take the count of how many times each of they are duplicated.

```
name <- c("A","A","A","B","B","c","D","A")
age <- c(22,23,22,32,32,54,65,70)
sex <- c("m","f","f","m","m","f","m","f")
both <- data.frame(name,age,sex)
both

both[!duplicated(both$name),]
```

Desired out put:

```
name    age sex count
A   70  f   4
B   32  m   2
C   54  f   1
D   65  m   1
```

Comment: Not clear about the expected.  Can you show the expected output.  Try `both[!(duplicated(both$name)|duplicated(both$name, fromLast = TRUE)),]`

Comment: If we need the frequency count use `table(both$name)` or `both %>% count(name)`

Comment: This combination also works  `both <- both%>%group_by(name)%>%mutate(sum(duplicated(name)))

both <- both[!duplicated(both$name),]`

Answer (score 0):

We can group by 'name', get the frequency count (`n()`), then `filter` the rows having the most frequency value of 'sex', and `slice` the last row

```
library(dplyr)
both %>% 
    group_by(name) %>%
    group_by(n = n(), add = TRUE) %>%
    filter(sex == Mode(sex)) %>% 
    slice(n())
# A tibble: 4 x 4
# Groups:   name, n [4]
#  name    age sex       n
#  <fct> <dbl> <fct> <int>
#1 A        70 f         4
#2 B        32 m         2
#3 c        54 f         1
#4 D        65 m         1
```

where

```
Mode <- function(x) {
  ux <- unique(x)
  ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
 }
```

Comment: My desired out put like name age sex count
A 70 f 4
B 32 m 2
C 54 f 1
D 65 m 1

Comment: My desired out put like name age sex count
A 70 f 4
B 32 m 2
C 54 f 1
D 65 m 1

Comment: @OmprakashJena  not able to read it properly.  can you update int your post

Comment: @OmprakashJena  Can you please check the updated answer

Answer (score 0):

This combination gives your result

```
both <- both%>%group_by(name)%>%mutate(Count = n())
both <- both%>%group_by(name)%>%slice(n())
```